# How do I get specific information out of Mediainfo

Tags: powershell, command-line, mediainfo

I found out that mediainfo is a really good tool for getting metadata out of videofiles. But sometimes its way too overwhelming for me. First thing I should mention I am using Windows Powershell and in Windows Powershell I use Mediainfo as command line tool. Works pretty neat, but when I use the normal XML output, like the one you can see with the GUI version of Mediainfo, I don't get enough informations out of my videofiles. When using the `--Full` command I get a better overview of metadata. Unfortunately I just need the fifth "Duration" information:

Duration: 00:04:42.520

but everytime I try to ask for the Duration by using `--Inform="Video;%Duration%"` I always get the first "Duration" information:

Duration: 282520

And now here is my question: Is it possible to use the Mediainfo commands in a way that I only get the timecode duration? Because I can't figure out which command would be the best to get this problem solved.

```
C:\Mediainfo>mediainfo.exe C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\input_luebeck\TheFascist.mov 
General
Count                                    : 292
Count of stream of this kind             : 1
Kind of stream                           : General
Kind of stream                           : General
Stream identifier                        : 0
Count of video streams                   : 1
Count of audio streams                   : 1
OtherCount                               : 1
Video_Format_List                        : ProRes
Video_Format_WithHint_List               : ProRes
Codecs Video                             : apch
Video_Language_List                      : English
Audio_Format_List                        : PCM
Audio_Format_WithHint_List               : PCM
Audio codecs                             : PCM
Audio_Language_List                      : English
Other_Format_List                        : QuickTime TC
Other_Format_WithHint_List               : QuickTime TC
Other_Language_List                      : English
Complete name                            : C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\input_luebeck\TheFascist.mov
Folder name                              : C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\input_luebeck
File name                                : TheFascist
File extension                           : mov
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format/Extensions usually used           : mp4 m4v m4a m4b m4p 3gpp 3gp 3gpp2 3g2 k3g jpm jpx mqv ismv isma f4v
Commercial name                          : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : QuickTime
Internet media type                      : video/mp4
Codec ID                                 : qt
Codec ID/Url                             : http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/standalone.html
Codec                                    : MPEG-4
Codec                                    : MPEG-4
Codec/Extensions usually used            : mp4 m4v m4a m4b m4p 3gpp 3gp 3gpp2 3g2 k3g jpm jpx mqv ismv isma f4v
File size                                : 5983768576
File size                                : 5.57 GiB
File size                                : 6 GiB
File size                                : 5.6 GiB
File size                                : 5.57 GiB
File size                                : 5.573 GiB
Duration                                 : 282520
Duration                                 : 4mn 42s
Duration                                 : 4mn 42s 520ms
Duration                                 : 4mn 42s
Duration                                 : 00:04:42.520
Overall bit rate mode                    : VBR
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 169439858
Overall bit rate                         : 169 Mbps
Stream size                              : 1062720
Stream size                              : 1.01 MiB (0%)
Stream size                              : 1 MiB
Stream size                              : 1.0 MiB
Stream size                              : 1.01 MiB
Stream size                              : 1.013 MiB
Stream size                              : 1.01 MiB (0%)
Proportion of this stream                : 0.00018
HeaderSize                               : 32
DataSize                                 : 5983559488
FooterSize                               : 209056
IsStreamable                             : No
Encoded date                             : UTC 2013-10-21 09:01:39
Tagged date                              : UTC 2013-10-21 09:15:35
File creation date                       : UTC 2014-09-29 14:30:28.168
File creation date (local)               : 2014-09-29 16:30:28.168
File last modification date              : UTC 2014-09-29 14:37:20.793
File last modification date (local)      : 2014-09-29 16:37:20.793
Writing library                          : Apple QuickTime
Writing library                          : Apple QuickTime
Writing library/Name                     : Apple QuickTime
Media/UUID                               : EF3223FC-064A-45E6-9F5D-E59BD682C489
Media/History/UUID                       : 2783B850-08F4-43DE-AEA5-3D8E7DD78570
```

Comment: At first i would have converted this to a hashtable but since there are several Duration keys that would not have worked. I support you could just pipe your command into `Select-String` like `mediainfo.exe C:\Users\path.avi | Select-String -Pattern "Duration"`. That would be a start. Or maybe use `Select-String -Pattern "Duration\s+:\s+\d{2}:\d{2}"` to just get the line `Duration : 00:04:42.520`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work with the Duration you get with the command you allready used like this:

(assuming $tmil holds the value)

```
# $tmil = 282520
$durationObject = [timespan]::FromMilliseconds($tmil)

#Minutes:
$durationObject.Minutes
#Seconds:
$durationObject.Seconds

#Duration in HH:MM:SS
$durationObject.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")

#Duration in HH:MM:SS,MS
$durationObject.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss\,fff")
```

The duration you get is in milliseconds and can easily be reformatted to fit your needs

Comment: Very clever. Build the time based on the return.

Comment: First of all, sorry for the late reply but I was very busy in the past two weeks, but now I found the time to try some of these answers here and this is the best answer, thanks a lot, tried it and it does everything I could have asked for. Upvoted your answer and accepted it as the best answer. Thanks to all the other guys though.

Answer (score 17):

Hidden features ;-)
Use

```
MediaInfo --Language=raw --Full
```

and you'll see the field name to use for the template

Here:

```
MediaInfo --Language=raw --Full --Inform="Video;%Duration/String4%"
```

PS: I (the main developer of MediaInfo) would see quicker questions if you post questions on the MediaInfo forum.

Comment: how can this work on widnows using mediainfo.exe ?

Comment: The example is with Windows MediaInfo command line (not the graphical interface. You need to use the CLI version of MediaInfo).

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting that text dumped and all that you want is the duration you can run it through a regex to get that:

```
$Duration = 'C:\Mediainfo\mediainfo.exe' 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\input_luebeck\TheFascist.mov' | Where{$_ -match "Duration\s+?: (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3})"}|ForEach{$Matches[1]}
```

That should set `$Duration` to `00:04:42.520` as you wanted.